# how to insert 10K records in mongodb consisting of Same keys and values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on server side development for the game application.

The game will have a spin wheel concept. For that purpose, I need to store 10k records for 100 coins and 5k records for 200 coins and 100 records for 500 coins and 1 record for 1000 coins as well as for 10000 coins.

I will store documents by running a cron job at the end of the day. And will remove all records of the previous day.

Every time the spin wheel will be called I will pick the random document from Available(Non utilized) document.

```
//Document Structure
{
    "No_of_Coins": 100,
    "position": 4,
    "Recorded_Spin": false,
    "date": new Date()
}
```

I can use for loop and can insert 10k records one after another.

But I need a speedy and efficient approach for the above Algorithm.

Comment: As the game users will increase the storing of records will be an increase from 10k to 1M and then 10M and will go on increasing. So I need the speedy and most efficient method for storing huge records at once for my algorithm.

Comment: what about using insertMany command for inserting more documents to mongoDB at a time ?

Comment: for insert many i have send array of 10000 documents

Comment: i need to insert same document 10000 times

Comment: yeah I got it. I meant that you can clone the document 10000 times and then you can use insertMany to put the cloned documents to db. I think this is one of the efficient methods.

Comment: but it will take lot for time for cloning. Can you put your detailed answer

Comment: yeah I posted one. Lets take a look at it and update me whether its helpful or not. If not we can try another one.

Comment: hi nikhil will test and update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a array what includes 10000 items, use `insertMany` method to insert all item to your db

```
var arrData = new Array(10000).fill({
    "No_of_Coins": 100,
    "position": 4,
    "Recorded_Spin": false,
    "date": new Date()
})

db.collection.insertMany(arrData);
```

Comment: Hi @hoangdv,
Suppose I use save
() method in combination with Promise.all instead of insertMany() to insert 10000 documents in turn, will it work?
And how is its performance compared to insertMany(), which one will be faster?

Answer (score 1):

```
const createArray = (arr,times,obj) => arr.flatMap((x,i) => Array(obj[i] || times).fill(x))
var arr = [{
"No_of_Coins": 100,
"position": 4,
"Recorded_Spin": false,
"date": new Date()
}]
var arr2 = createArray(arr,1000,arr[0])
console.log(arr2)
```

Lets try this one.

Comment: Hi nikhil thanks for spending your valuable time and support. But hoangdv solution is efficient for me.